# JDeveloper - change the target URL when running with the internal OC4J container

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm trying to set up JDeveloper for development on an internal terminal server. When I run a newly created webpage using the internal OC4J container, my browser opens looking at page `http://hostname.domain:8988/OA_HTML/runregion.jsp`.

For reasons out of my control, the DNS server won't resolve hostname.domain for me. In production, this won't be an issue, but for testing, having to deploy and test on the full dev instance every time is a problem.

Is there a way to tell Jdeveloper to use `127.0.0.1` for the testing URL rather than `hostname.domain`?

Comment: so put an entry in hosts file.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have permission to do that (and the admin around getting permission is stupidly bad). This is a shared terminal server, not my own development PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change it in the "properties" of the "IntegratedWebLogic"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it. It's slightly different on my version - I'm using JDeveloper 10.1.3.3, with the embedded OC4J server (because that's the version certified for use with the eBusiness version we have), and it's under "Embedded OC4J Server Preferences" under "Startup" - http://imgur.com/jOOzjry